# sql query which finds how many rows are in each group where some data is

Tags: sql

I hope you help me to perform this sql query.

I have a table like this one:

```
Group | Person ID | ...more columns

10   |   abc1

10   |   abc2

15   |   abc1

15   |   abc3

15   |   abc4

20   |   abc5

20   |   abc2
```

As you might see, the abc1 person ID is in two groups, so I want to perform a query which find what groups the abc1 person ID belongs and count how much people are in each group where the abc1 person ID is.

The result that I expect is something like this

```
Group where abc1 ID person is | Members

         10        |          2
         15        |          3
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You've got some product specific answers...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
Select groupid as "Group", count(groupid) as "Members"
FROM Test t where groupid in 
(SELECT groupid
FROM Test 
where personid = "abc1"
GROUP BY groupid)
Group by groupid;
```

As group is a keyword, so might have to use a different name of field.
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/474e7/21) here

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Hope it helps.

```
SELECT group_id, count(*) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE person_id = 'abc1'
GROUP BY group_id;`
```

Also `group` is a reserved keyword in SQL, so it's better if you use something else like `group_id` for the column name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT group_id, count(*) 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN person_id = 'abc1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 select Groupid,count(*) from Test where Groupid in (
 select distinct(t.Groupid) from Test t where t.personid="abc1")
 group by 1;
```

Verified on this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/474e7/35).

Comment: `distinct` is not a function, it's a part of `select distinct`. Skip those redundant parentheses and simply do `select distinct t.Groupid from Test t` - to make things clearer.

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers (object names), use single quotes for string literals, e.g. `'abc1'`.